# CDF of $Y=\sin X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, inverse-function

Given that the random variable $X$ is having pdf given by:
$$f_X(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{2}{3\pi} & \text { for } \frac{-\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \pi, \\ 0 & \text { else } \end{cases}$$ Find the CDF of the random variable $Y=\sin X$ without finding the pdf.

My try:

Case $1.$ When $y \leq -1$, we have $F_Y(y)=0$

Case $2.$ When $y \in (-1,0)$, we have $$F_Y(y)=P(-1<\sin X \leq y)=P(-\frac{\pi}{2}<\sin^{-1}(\sin X)\leq \sin^{-1}(y))=P(\frac{-\pi}{2}<X \leq \sin^{-1}(y))$$
So we get
$$F_Y(y)=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\sin^{-1}(y)}\frac{2}{3\pi}{dy}=\frac{2}{3\pi}\left(\sin^{-1}y+\frac{\pi}{2}\right),\:-1<y<0$$

But i am unable to do for $0<y<1$

Comment: What you need is $\sin^{-1}((-\infty,x]) \cap [-\pi/2,\pi]$. Can you figure out what this set is? Note that it will not just be an interval when $0<x<1$.

Comment: Basically what i did is when $0<y<1$, we have $F_Y(y)=P\left(\sin X \leq y\right)+P\left(\pi-\sin^{-1}y\leq X \leq \pi\right) $

Comment: You have $P(\sin(X) \leq y)$ regardless. The point is that $\{ \sin(X) \leq y \}$ consists of $[-\pi/2,\arcsin(y)]$ together with $[\pi-\arcsin(y),\pi]$, if $0<y<1$.

Comment: When $y>0$ why won't it be $[0, \sin^{-1}y]$ together with $[\pi -\sin^{-1}y, \pi]$?

Comment: Because if $x \in [-\pi/2,0]$ then $\sin(X)<0 \leq y$. (I would suggest using $\arcsin$ notation, by the way, it is more explicit which I find helps with avoiding pitfalls like this.)